# Display div overflow-x scrollbar without setting the width of div?

Tags: css, html, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

```
#main {
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
width: 95%;
}
#left-wrapper {
display: block;
}
#content {
height: 500px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: scroll;
}

<div id="main">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id='left-wrapper'>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id='content'>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The content wrapper contains a table which holds some data which size is unknown, and must not be wrapped so white-space:nowrap is set, and it works fine. The height of the content div has a fixed size and the vertical scrollbar appears ok. The main div's width is set to 95%. The problem is that the content div does not activates the scrollbar when the data is too long to fit, instead it resizes itself to the right side of the screen, even if the wrapper main div's width is set to 95%. Is there a way to activate the content div's horizontal scrollbar without setting it's width? It's maximum width should be in line with the width of the main wrapper, it would not be a problem even if it has a fixed width, but then it must fill the remaining area to be in line with it's wrapper main div which as I mentioned has it's width set to 95%.
I searched everywhere, days are passing and I simply can't figure out a right solution. Please if anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner `<div>` will stay inside the container `<div>` with the CSS you have. But, because you have a `<table>` surrounding the inner `<div>` it doesn't behave as expected.

I think the solution may be to layout the page without the `<table>`.

This example shows the inner `<div>` being constrained inside the outer `<div>` using your current CSS.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #main {border:solid 2px orange; margin: auto;   padding: 0; width: 190px;}
    #left-wrapper {display: block;}
    #content {border:solid 2px purple;  height: 500px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: auto;   overflow-x: scroll;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">

      <div id='content'>
         <table style="border:solid 1px #ddd;">
            <tr style="background-color:#ccccff;">
               <td>column A</td>
               <td>column B</td>
               <td>column C</td>
               <td>column D</td>
               <td>column E</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```